# Reference (or proof) of: classifying map $u\colon M \to K(\pi,1)$ induces $H^1(\pi_1(M);\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong H^1(M; \mathbb{Z}/2)$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I'm try to understanding a survey chapter in Angeloni - Metzler -Sieradski  ["Two dimensional Homotopy and combinatorial group theory"](https://books.google.de/books?hl=it&id=IdRsF_mezbIC&q=stable%20classification#v=snippet&q=stable%20classification&f=false) namely the one about Stable classification of $4$-manifold (see link).

Now he claims that the classifying map for the universal cover  of $M$ $$u\colon M \to K(\pi_1(M),1)$$ induces an isomorphism $H^1(\pi_1(M);\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong H^1(M; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ and gives as a reference the well - known book of Brown "Cohomology of groups". I tried proving the result directly but something missing. And I'm unable to find the exact position of the result inside the mentioned book.

Can someone point me out in which chapter is this result proved on Brown's book or giving me some hints to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $u$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$.  By universal coefficients theorem and the Hurewicz theorem, for any path-connected space $X$ and any abelian group $G$, there is a natural isomorphisms $H^1(X,G)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(X),G))\cong\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X),G)$.  Thus $u$ induces an isomorphism on $H^1$ with any coefficients.

Comment: I'm checking the definition of classifying map, on tom Dieck's is the $G$-map covered by a bundle map $\tilde{M}\to E\pi_1(M)$ given by the fact that $E\pi_1(M)$ is a terminal object. So the fact that induces iso is a consequence of this?

Comment: Right, because $E\pi_1(M)$ is contractible, so the fundamental groups of both $M$ and $K(\pi_1(M),1)$ are isomorphic to $\pi_1(M)$ via the action of $\pi_1(M)$ on $\tilde{M}$ and $E\pi_1(M)$.  Since the map $\tilde{M}\to E\pi_1(M)$ preserves this action, the induced map $M\to K(\pi_1(M),1)$ is an isomorphism on $\pi_1$.